# Python error: the following arguments are required: --config

Tags: python, parsing, pycharm, google-colaboratory, config

```
usage: main.py [-h] --config CONFIG
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: --config
```

I tried to run the "main.py" file from python but I am getting this error. It is originally works on google colab. But when I try it in PyCharm it shows this error. I used the following codes to run it on google colab.

```
!git clone https://github.com/ZhuoxuCui/K_UNN.git
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
!pip install mat73
%cp -r /content/drive/MyDrive/K_UNN/* /content/K_UNN/
```

The below code to run it:

```
%cd /content/K_UNN
!python main.py --config /content/K_UNN/configs/config.yaml
```

main.py file:

```
def parse_args_and_config():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--config', type=str, required=True,  help='Path to the config file')

args = parser.parse_args()

# parse config file
with open(os.path.join('configs', args.config), 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.Loader)
new_config = dict2namespace(config)

# set random seed
init_seeds(new_config.seed)

# GPU setup


return args, new_config

def main():
args, config = parse_args_and_config()

runner = Runner(args, config)

if config.mode.testing:
    runner.test()

return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

The upper portion is main.py file.

Comment: Fix your function indentation.

Comment: Wait, so are you not doing `python main.py --config /content/K_UNN/configs/config.yaml`?

Comment: which path should I use?

Comment: That's all based on your own system and whatever config file you have. What does your directory structure look like? Do you know where this YAML file is on your own machine?

Comment: How are you running it from PyCharm? If you're using the terminal window you shouldn't need `!`

Comment: python main.py --config /content/K_UNN/configs/config.yaml . I tried this but it shows "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/K_UNN/configs/config.yaml' but the config.yaml is in the configs folder

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct absolute path to your config? It would mean your local path is exactly the same as the path on Google Colab (which wouldn't be odd, but in general you'd have to explicitly make a root directory called `/content` on pretty much any system.